# Cannot receive data from PC to Android via Sockets

Tags: android, c++, sockets

I have my PC set up as Server and my Android phone as Client. I have verified that the Server is sending data by using `telnet` command in Windows. My phone can connect to the Server, but is not receiving/displaying data.

I use this code to send data in **PC** -

```
char msg[32] = "message";
int sent = send(new_socket, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
```

And I use this code to receive data in **Android** -

```
public void onClickConnect(View view) {
    serverIP = textIP.getText().toString();
    new ConnectTask().execute("");
}

public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(serverIP, new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                Log.i("Debug","Input message: " + message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();
        return null;
    }
}
--- TcpClient.java ---
public class TcpClient {

private String SERVER_IP;
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
private String mServerMessage;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;
private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

public TcpClient(String IPAddress, OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
    SERVER_IP = IPAddress;
}

public void run() {
    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
        try {
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (mRun) {
                mBufferIn.readLine(mServerMessage);
                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

Comment: In your example, what is the use of `buffer` when you can just send `msg` directly? Also, never use any `printf` function with a buffer for format, use e.g. `sprintf_s(buffer, "%s", msg);` instead (the reason should be easy to understand if `msg` was input from a user instead of a static string, think about what would happen if the user entered input with formatting codes).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have changed the code now. The `buffer` was for another part of a code.

Comment: I couldn't fix this problem so I had to reverse the connection, make my PC client and my phone Server.